# rewriting multilingual website using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code to rewrite my website in order to use subfolder language:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|fr)
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$  $1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

When i try on localhost working fine, but once i upload online, i need to do this in order to change the language:

```
http://localhost/en/en/
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost/en/
```

I got redirected to this url too sometimes:

```
http://localhost/fr/?lang=en
```

When i enter into:

```
http://localhost/en/
```

**UPDATE**

When i put: `var_dump($_GET);`

I have this result:

```
array (size=1)
  'page' => string 'accueil?lang=en' (length=15)
```

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

DirectoryIndex page/index.php?page=accueil

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|fr)
RewriteRule ^$ fr/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)$  $1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)/?$ page/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But the `CSS/JS` and some other pages do not works, work only for some pages.

Comment: You could try to add `RewriteBase /` just to make sure the base is correct but that's a weird behaviour.

Comment: I already did that, not solved the problem sir.

Comment: Try to add `Options -Multiviews` at the top of your `.htaccess` file. It might be enabled on the online server and will cause all kinds of issues when coupled with rewrite rules.

Comment: @Capsule i get same result: `array (size=1)
  'page' => string 'accueil?lang=fr' (length=15)`, must modify this rule : `RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` in order to get it working for all pages. But no idea on how to do that.

Comment: I would definitely recommend having a look at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog and comparing the logs of your local and online servers to understand what's different in the way redirections/rewrites work.

Comment: I already did that but it is complicated, is for this i am asking help, thank you for the advice.

Comment: Well, in this case you should post the logs to help people solve your problem :-) The rules look fine, and indeed, they work fine on your local setup.